# SAML Response - How to verify the signature inside it?

Tags: azure-active-directory, saml-2.0

I want to verify a SAML Response created by Azure AD.
The response looks like this:

```
<samlp:Response ID="_188301aa-efa1-405f-ad6d-cf0ae65e347b" Version="2.0" IssueInstant="2023-09-27T18:28:02.720Z" Destination="some destination..."
    xmlns:samlp="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol">
    <Issuer
        xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">some...
    </Issuer>
    <Signature
        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
        <SignedInfo>
            <CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
            <SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256"/>
            <Reference URI="#_188301aa-efa1-405f-ad6d-cf0ae65e347b">
                <Transforms>
                    <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature"/>
                    <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
                </Transforms>
                <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256"/>
                <DigestValue>...</DigestValue>
            </Reference>
        </SignedInfo>
        <SignatureValue>...</SignatureValue>
        <KeyInfo>
            <ds:X509Data
                xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
                <ds:X509Certificate>...</ds:X509Certificate>
            </ds:X509Data>
        </KeyInfo>
    </Signature>
    <samlp:Status>
        <samlp:StatusCode Value="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:status:Success"/>
    </samlp:Status>
    <Assertion ID="_bcc97cde-fe0d-4f41-92df-4a32348c1c00" IssueInstant="2023-09-27T18:28:02.719Z" Version="2.0"
        xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">
        <Issuer>.../</Issuer>
        <Subject>
            <NameID Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:emailAddress">...</NameID>
            <SubjectConfirmation Method="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:cm:bearer">
                <SubjectConfirmationData NotOnOrAfter="2023-09-27T19:28:02.519Z" Recipient="..."/>
            </SubjectConfirmation>
        </Subject>
        <Conditions NotBefore="2023-09-27T18:23:02.519Z" NotOnOrAfter="2023-09-27T19:28:02.519Z">
            <AudienceRestriction>
                <Audience>matansso</Audience>
            </AudienceRestriction>
        </Conditions>
        <AttributeStatement>
            ...
        </AttributeStatement>
        <AuthnStatement AuthnInstant="2023-09-19T13:39:36.939Z" SessionIndex="_bcc97cde-fe0d-4f41-92df-4a32348c1c00">
            <AuthnContext>
                <AuthnContextClassRef>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:ac:classes:Password</AuthnContextClassRef>
            </AuthnContext>
        </AuthnStatement>
    </Assertion>
</samlp:Response>
```

Note: the original response (after base64 decoded) is an xml without whitespaces.
Note: in Azure AD SSO settings, I set the "SAML Signing Option" to "SAML Response".
After reading on google, I understood I need to extract from the xml 2 values:

1. SignatureValue
2. X509Certificate

Then, I need to verify the SignatureValue using the X509Certificate and the entire xml string.
I tried to do that using Node.js, here is what I did:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const crypto = require('crypto');

const samlResponse  = '<samlp:Response...>...</samlp:Response>' //the entire xml string
const signatureValue = '...' //the value inside <SignatureValue> tag
const x509Certificate = '...' //the value inside <ds:X509Certificate> tag
const cert = `-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\n${x509Certificate}\n-----END CERTIFICATE-----`;

// Verify the signature
const verifier = crypto.createVerify('RSA-SHA256');
verifier.update(samlResponse, 'utf8');

const isSignatureValid = verifier.verify(cert, signatureValue, 'base64');

if (isSignatureValid) {
    console.log('SAML Response signature is valid.');
} else {
    console.error('SAML Response signature is invalid.');
}
```

But when I run this script, the output is always: "SAML Response signature is invalid."
Am I missing something?

Thanks.
I searched a lot on google, stack overflow, azure ad api reference and azure ad SAML reference.

Comment: Why build your own validation mechanism rather than using one of the known open source (or paid) SAML integrations for node or nearly any other framework? You're playing with a security system, which may be useless or harmful if you don't get it right.

Comment: @AndrewK. Thanks for your reply. I want to know how the mechanism works